# Why are the wave heights of higher order beam vibrations asymptotically approach $1/\sqrt{2}$ of peak amplitude?

Tags: classical-mechanics, elasticity, vibrations

I calculated and graphed several higher order harmonics of the free vibrations of a cantilever beam and I noticed something peculiar.

[image: fig1]

All the wave heights in the middle of the beam have almost exactly $1/\sqrt{2}$ times the amplitude of the end of the beam. Even from the 3rd harmonic and up, for the modes with non-zero end deflection, the peaks in the middle parts of the beam *all have the same amplitude* and this approaches a fixed value as the frequency goes up.

This is a result of the standard beam vibration equation

$$ E I \tfrac{\partial^4 y}{\partial x^4} + \frac{m}{\ell} \tfrac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2} = 0$$ and the mode shapes

$$ y(x) = A \left( \sin\left( \Phi \frac{x}{\ell}\right) - \sinh\left( \Phi \frac{x}{\ell}\right) \right) + B \left( \cos\left( \Phi \frac{x}{\ell}\right) - \cosh\left( \Phi \frac{x}{\ell}\right) \right) $$

So I am wondering what is it in the propagation of transverse waves in a beam that limits the amplitude and what implications does it have for the transfer of vibration energy (and the limits therein) in higher harmonics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the values of $A$ and $B$ given the boundary conditions:
$$
A = -\frac12\frac{\cos \frac{\pi  n}{2}+\cosh \frac{\pi  n}{2}}{\cos \frac{\pi  n}{2} \sinh \frac{\pi  n}{2}-\sin\frac{\pi  n}{2} \cosh \frac{\pi  n}{2}} = -\frac12,
$$
for $n=3+4k$ (the modes you are considering)

$$
B = \frac12 \frac{\sin \frac{\pi  n}{2}+\sinh\frac{\pi  n}{2}}{\cos \frac{\pi  n}{2} \sinh \frac{\pi  n}{2}-\sin\frac{\pi  n}{2} \cosh \frac{\pi  n}{2}}=
\frac12\frac{\sinh\frac{\pi  n}{2}-1}{\cosh\frac{\pi  n}{2}} \approx \frac12
$$
for $n=3+4k$ (for $n=3$ it differs from $1/2$ the most and is equal to $0.491$ which is still close enough)

In other words for the modes you are considering, the shape equation is almost ($l=1$):
$$
y(x) = \frac12\left(\cos\frac{\pi nx}{2}-\sin\frac{\pi nx}{2}\right) + \frac12\left(\sinh\frac{\pi nx}{2}-\cosh\frac{\pi nx}{2}\right) =\\ -\frac1{\sqrt2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi nx}{2}-\frac\pi4\right) -\frac12 e^{-\frac{\pi nx}{2}}
$$

This approximation is off near $x=1$, but in general, you should be able to see how your effect comes into existence.

Comment: Yes, that is it. $|A|=|B|=\tfrac{1}{2}$ for those mode shapes. Also $A+B=0$ which reminds me of the standing wave solution(s) for a string, but for a beam.

Comment: It happens because the beam can “sense” the boundary conditions at a distance $\approx\lambda$. So as the higher harmonics are considered, most of the beam is essentially a free beam with sinusoidal standing wave.

Comment: Look at page 210 of [this great lecture notes](https://ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/mavt/mechanical-systems/mm-dam/documents/Notes/Dynamics_LectureNotes.pdf#page=214) and the exact same plot, and mentioning earlier that solutions to standing waves is what is sought after to solve the equations of motion.